# The image of a Banach space under a continuous, linear, open map is a Banach space.

Tags: analysis

This is an exercise from Royden's *Real Analysis*. Suppose $X$ is a Banach space, there is a continuous, linear, open map from $X$ onto a normed linear space $Y$. Show that $Y$ is Banach.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints.** Let $T$ be your linear map. Show first that there exists a finite constant $C$ such that, for any $y\in Y$, one can find $x\in X$ such that $Tx=y$ and $\Vert x\Vert\leq C\,\Vert y\Vert$. Use this to show that any series $\sum y_n$ in $Y$ such that $\sum_0^\infty \Vert y_n\Vert<\infty$ is convergent in $Y$.

Comment: Etienne, thanks for help. I was thinking constructing an homeomorphism between X/KerT and Y which I thought was possible.

Comment: This is indeed possible. You can use open-ness to show that the induced map from $X/\ker(T)$ onto $Y$ has a continuous inverse.